# React Material Treeview, Tree node not expanding on click when using expanded property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

Treeview not expanding on manual click when using expanded property, not sure why it's not expanding

```
<TreeView
                className={classes.root}
                defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
                expanded={nodeIds}
                selected={props.nodeId.toString()}
                defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
                defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
            >
                {GetTreeItemsFromData(props.treeItems)}
            </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs of the `TreeView API` from the Material-UI, to expand a node, you need to pass in the node IDs as an array into either `expanded` or `defaultExpanded`.

So if you can't expand a node, perhaps you can try to see if `nodeIds` is an array in the state first, then see if you properly trigger a re-render when you update the state. If not, then probably you have not yet set up this state properly.

Reference: [TreeView API](https://material-ui.com/api/tree-view/)

Comment: I said its expanding, but onclick expanding/collapsing not working

Comment: That's what you have to update when you perform these actions. When you click an item, it should update the variable `nodeIds` in the state, either append the target id or remove it from the array, so that it can trigger a re-render.